# Find Background running apps in iphone

Tags: ios

can any one help me . I want to retrieve applications name which are running in background only.

I need name of apps only, programmatically (by coding).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of code in which you want to retrieve application name. Is programmatically means language. Please explain more

Comment: using c or objective-c definitely

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get a list of running processes. See this answer: [Return a list of running background apps/processes in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906180/return-a-list-of-running-background-apps-processes-in-ios).

However, you only get process names (not the whole application name's or titles), which might be misleading or there may be same names for different applications.

Comment: I need the process type only i.e is it running in background or foreground

Comment: in ios there is only one application in foreground - that is your app. All other are in background.

Comment: //Get frontmost application
char frontmostAppS[256];
memset(frontmostAppS,sizeof(frontmostAppS),0);
SBFrontmostApplicationDisplayIdentifier(p,frontmostAppS);
NSString * frontmostApp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",frontmostAppS];
//NSLog(@"Frontmost app is %@",frontmostApp);
//get list of running apps from SpringBoard
NSArray *allApplications = SBSCopyApplicationDisplayIdentifiers(p,NO, NO);
 for(NSString *identifier in allApplications) {
 NSString *locName=SBSCopyLocalizedApplicationNameForDisplayIdentifier(p,identifier);NSLog(@"Active Application:%@",identifier);
 }

Comment: I want to use this code in my app , but I am getting error     Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SBSCopyLocalizedApplicationNameForDisplayIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[ViewController getActiveApps] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

it will not run on iOS 8 as apple take is as a vulnerability to get the process id of current running app.but you can get a list of all the processes running in background or foreground.

Comment: This is not really an answer imho. Could you provide some support for your claim, please? E.g. show with code how it could be done.

Comment: this link will give you all the list of processes running
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by