# how to determine which apps are background and which app is foreground on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

My application is a background application i.e it is always running in background , how can I determine which apps are background and which app is foreground on iOS by application id

any one have any idea about this .
Thanks.

Comment: Your solution is from [Here][1] and also [here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906180/return-a-list-of-running-background-apps-processes-in-ios
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a   thanks @anonymous and Michael Dautermann

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with an App Store app.