# Can I get info about apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some ideas for new apps.
And I have one question. Can I get information about launched apps?  I need only names of this apps. Is it real to make? And if it is realizable, will it will be accepted by appStore?

Comment: What do you mean by "Can I get information about launched apps?" ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: For example. If you will doubleClick on Home button, using iPod/iPhone, you will see menu with launched apps. Can I get the same list in my app?

Comment: Only on a jailbroken device, otherwise no. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906180/return-a-list-of-running-background-apps-processes-in-ios

Comment: Here we can see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this. You'll need process names of apps, not their AppStore names.
[How to get information about free memory and running processes in an App Store approved app? (Yes, there is one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a)